# Related to textArea component in flash

Tags: flash

I am facing a problem while using textAreacomponent in Flash cs4.I set the text of this component at run time with coding i.e dynamic text and after that i am rotating this component with -2.After rotation it dosen't show the text why is it so?ny 1

Comment: 13 questions, no accepted answers - you might get a better response if you read the StackOverflow FAQ on how to **accept answers**, it's a good way to say thank you to those who have helped you!

Answer (score 0):

you have to be using embedded text to show rotation.